# Graph API - Update SharePoint Library Fields after Drive Upload

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am uploading files via the Microsoft Graph Rest API for SharePoint Online. I am leveraging the Drive Upload API to push files into a document library but I am not seeing a easy method to set field values on a file after or during the upload. Reviewing the API documentation, it appears you can leverage the List API to update/set fields, but you have to first find the id of the list object (file) and then perform the patch to update the fields. I am curious if there is a method that uses the file Id or some other tag I get from the upload to easily set field values?

I am leveraging the following for uploads:

```
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

It appears I need to find the new file I uploaded by name, then patch the fields I want set:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields
```

**Post Answer Edit:**

You can get the List ID value by going through the relationship of the drive object.

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/ListItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An item in a SharePoint document library is a linked item consisting of the DriveItem and the ListItem. Your PUT-Request returns the created DriveItem. Each DriveItem has a property called listItem, which contains the linked ListItem.
You can use the property id of the linked listItem to update the item directly without searching for the ListItem. First, upload the document and wait for the response:

```
var driveItem = PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

Next, get the item id of the ListItem:

```
var listItemId = driveItem.ListItem.Id
```

Then, update the ListItem:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{listItemId}/fields
```

So far, I have not come across an easier way to do this.

Comment: Just to clarify, you need to go through the relationship of ListItem to get the ID. Thanks so much for the help here.

Comment: Yes, you need the id and you need to make at least two requests. It would be nice, if you could pass-in the fields for the ListItem directly with the request to upload the document. But, the property listItem is read-only: [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0).